# Incorporate honeypot into my .php file

Tags: php

I am trying to add a honeypot field to my form and every thing I have researched I cannot understand where to place the code. Any help would be appreciated. Here is what I have:

```
<div class="hide">
    <label for="spam">What is two plus two?</label>
    <input name="spam" type="text" size="4" id="spam">
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
.hide {display: none;}
```

Here is the .php that I am trying to incorporate in my .php file:

```
    $spa = $_POST["spam"];

if (!empty($spa) && !($spa == "4" || $spa == "four")) {
    echo "You failed the bot test!";
    exit ();
}
```

Here is the .php file itself:

```
<?php

class contactForm{


    function contactForm($cfg)
    {


        $this->cfg['email_address'] = isset($cfg['email_address'])?$cfg['email_address']:'';

        // =?UTF-8?B? required to avoid bad character encoding in the From field
        // é (keeps utf-8 encoding in the file)
        $this->cfg['email_from'] = (isset($cfg['email_from']) && $cfg['email_from'])?'=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($cfg['email_from']).'?=':$this->cfg['email_address'];
        $this->cfg['email_address_cc'] = isset($cfg['email_address_cc'])?$cfg['email_address_cc']:'';
        $this->cfg['email_address_bcc'] = isset($cfg['email_address_bcc'])?$cfg['email_address_bcc']:'';

        $this->cfg['timezone'] = isset($cfg['timezone'])?$cfg['timezone']:'';

        $this->cfg['adminnotification_subject'] = isset($cfg['adminnotification_subject'])?$cfg['adminnotification_subject']:'';

        $this->cfg['usernotification_insertformdata'] = isset($cfg['usernotification_insertformdata'])?$cfg['usernotification_insertformdata']:'';
        $this->cfg['usernotification_inputid'] = isset($cfg['usernotification_inputid'])?$cfg['usernotification_inputid']:'';
        $this->cfg['usernotification_subject'] = isset($cfg['usernotification_subject'])?$cfg['usernotification_subject']:'';
        $this->cfg['usernotification_message'] = isset($cfg['usernotification_message'])?preg_replace('#<br(\s*)/>|<br(\s*)>#i', "\r\n",$cfg['usernotification_message']):'';

        $this->cfg['form_name'] = isset($cfg['form_name'])?$cfg['form_name']:'';

        $this->cfg['form_errormessage_captcha'] = isset($cfg['form_errormessage_captcha'])?$cfg['form_errormessage_captcha']:'';
        $this->cfg['form_errormessage_emptyfield'] = isset($cfg['form_errormessage_emptyfield'])?$cfg['form_errormessage_emptyfield']:'';
        $this->cfg['form_errormessage_invalidemailaddress'] = isset($cfg['form_errormessage_invalidemailaddress'])?$cfg['form_errormessage_invalidemailaddress']:'';
        $this->cfg['form_validationmessage'] = isset($cfg['form_validationmessage'])?$cfg['form_validationmessage']:'';
        $this->cfg['form_redirecturl'] = isset($cfg['form_redirecturl'])?$cfg['form_redirecturl']:'';

        $this->dash_line = '--------------------------------------------------------------';

        $this->mail_content_type_format = 'plaintext'; // html

        if($this->mail_content_type_format == 'plaintext')
        {
            $this->mail_content_type_format_charset = 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8';
            $this->mail_line_break = "\r\n";
        }
        if($this->mail_content_type_format == 'html')
        {
            $this->mail_content_type_format_charset = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8';
            $this->mail_line_break = "<br />";
        }


        /**
         * USER NOTIFICATION MAIL FORMAT
         */
        $this->cfg['usernotification_format'] = isset($cfg['usernotification_format'])?$cfg['usernotification_format']:'';

        if($this->cfg['usernotification_format'] == 'plaintext')
        {
            $this->mail_content_type_format_charset_usernotification = 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8';
            $this->mail_line_break_usernotification = "\r\n";
        }

        if($this->cfg['usernotification_format'] == 'html')
        {
            $this->mail_content_type_format_charset_usernotification = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8';
            $this->mail_line_break_usernotification = "<br />";
        }


        $this->merge_post_index = 0;

        $this->demo = 0;

        $this->envato_link = '';
    }


    function sendMail($param)
    {
        $count_files_to_attach = 0;

        // grab and insert the form URL in the notification message
        $form_url = (@$_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 'https://' : 'http://';

        if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != '80')
        {
            $form_url .= $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].':'.$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'].rawurlencode($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
        }
        else 
        {
            $form_url .= $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].rawurlencode($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
        }

        $form_url = str_replace('%2F', '/', $form_url);

        $form_url_exp = explode('/', $form_url);


        // remove contactform/inc/form-validation.php
        $pattern_slash = $form_url_exp[count($form_url_exp)-3].'/'.$form_url_exp[count($form_url_exp)-2].'/'.$form_url_exp[count($form_url_exp)-1];

        $form_url = str_replace($pattern_slash, '', $form_url);

        if($this->cfg['timezone'])
        {
            date_default_timezone_set($this->cfg['timezone']);
        }

        // g:i A | 01:37 AM
        // G:i | 13:37
        $mail_body = $this->cfg['adminnotification_subject'].': '.@date("F jS, Y, G:i")
                            .$this->mail_line_break.$this->mail_line_break.$this->cfg['form_name']
                            .$this->mail_line_break.$this->mail_line_break.'Form URL: '
                            .$this->mail_line_break.$form_url
                            .$this->mail_line_break.$this->dash_line;

        if($this->merge_post)
        {
            foreach($this->merge_post as $value)
            {
                if(
                   isset($value['element_type']) && $value['element_type'] == 'upload'
                   && isset($value['filename']) && $value['filename']
                   )
                {

                    if( isset($value['deletefile']) && ($value['deletefile'] == 1 || $value['deletefile'] == 2) )
                    {
                        $count_files_to_attach++;
                    }


                    $explode_requesturi = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
                    //print_r($explode_requesturi);

                    $explode_requesturi = explode('/',$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
                    //print_r($explode_requesturi);

                    $inc_form_validation = $explode_requesturi[count($explode_requesturi)-2].'/'.$explode_requesturi[count($explode_requesturi)-1] ;

                    $install_dir = str_replace($inc_form_validation,'',$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);



                    $mail_body .= $this->mail_line_break.$this->mail_line_break.$value['elementlabel_value'].': '.$value['element_value'];

                    // No file link if we delete the file after the upload
                    // 1: File Attachment + Download Link
                    // 2: File Attachment Only
                    if( isset($value['deletefile']) && ($value['deletefile'] == 1 || $value['deletefile'] == 3) )
                    {
                        $mail_body .= $this->mail_line_break
                                            .'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
                                            .str_replace('%2F', '/', rawurlencode($install_dir.'upload/'.$value['element_value']));
                    }

                } 
                else{
                    $mail_body .= $this->mail_line_break.$this->mail_line_break.$value['elementlabel_value'].': '.$value['element_value'];
                }
            }
        }

        $mail_body .= $this->mail_line_break.$this->mail_line_break.$this->dash_line;
        $mail_body .= $this->mail_line_break.'IP address: '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $mail_body .= $this->mail_line_break.'Host: '.gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

        if(preg_match('#html#', $this->mail_content_type_format_charset))
        {
            $mail_body = nl2br($mail_body);
        }

        if($this->demo != 1)
        {
            // for the admin: if the user provides his email address, it will appear in the "from" field
            $param['reply_emailaddress'] = (isset($param['reply_emailaddress']) && $param['reply_emailaddress'])?$param['reply_emailaddress']:$this->cfg['email_address'];

            // for the admin: if the user provides his email address, it will appear in the "reply-to" field
            $replyto_name = $param['reply_emailaddress']?$param['reply_emailaddress']:'';
            $replyto_address = $param['reply_emailaddress']?$param['reply_emailaddress']:'';

            $mailheaders_options = array(
                                                        'from'=>array('name'=>$param['reply_emailaddress'], 'address'=>$param['reply_emailaddress']),
                                                        'replyto'=>array('name'=>$replyto_name, 'address'=>$replyto_address),
                                                        'cc'=>array('address'=>$this->cfg['email_address_cc']),
                                                        'bcc'=>array('address'=>$this->cfg['email_address_bcc'])
                                                       );




            $mailheaders = $this->getMailHeaders($mailheaders_options);


            //if(!isset($param['uploads']) || !$param['uploads'])
            if(!$count_files_to_attach)
            {
                $mailheaders .= $this->mail_content_type_format_charset."\r\n";

                $mailmessage = $mail_body;
            } else
            {

                // boundary 
                $semi_rand = md5(time());
                $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

                // headers for attachment 
                $mailheaders .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
                                        ."Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n"
                                        ." boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

                // multipart boundary 

                $mailmessage = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n"
                                        ."--{$mime_boundary}\n"
                                        .$this->mail_content_type_format_charset."\n"
                                        ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n"
                                        .$mail_body
                                        ."\n\n";

                $mailmessage .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

                // preparing attachments
                $count_attached_file = 0;

                foreach($this->merge_post as $value)
                {
                        if(
                            isset($value['element_type']) && $value['element_type'] == 'upload'
                            && isset($value['filename']) && $value['filename']
                            && isset($value['deletefile']) && ($value['deletefile'] == 1 || $value['deletefile'] == 2)                                                                     
                        )
                        {
                            $count_attached_file++;

                            $file = fopen('../upload/'.$value['filename'],"rb");
                            $data = fread($file,filesize('../upload/'.$value['filename']));
                            fclose($file);

                            $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

                            $mailmessage .= 'Content-Type: {"application/octet-stream"};'."\n" . ' name="'.$value['filename'].'"'."\n" 
                                                    .'Content-Disposition: attachment;'."\n" . ' filename="'.$value['filename'].'"'."\n" 
                                                    .'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64'."\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";

                            // "--" must be added for the last file, or an empty file will be also attached in the message
                            if($count_attached_file == $count_files_to_attach)
                            {
                                $mailmessage .= "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
                            } else{
                                $mailmessage .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
                            }

                            // delete attached file?
                            // this is different from deleting the file when the user deletes the file himself in the from: check form-validation.php for this (in form-validation.php because the file must be deleted even if sendMail() is not called - when there are errors for example)
                            if(isset($value['deletefile']) && $value['deletefile'] == 2)
                            {
                                @unlink('../upload/'.$value['filename']);
                            }
                        }
                } // foreach
            } // if(!$count_files_to_attach)

            @mail($this->cfg['email_address'], $this->cfg['adminnotification_subject'], $mailmessage, $mailheaders);

        }
    }


    function sendMailReceipt($value)
    {
        if($this->demo != 1)
        {

            $mailheaders_options = array(
                                                        'from'=>array('name'=>$this->cfg['email_from'], 'address'=>$this->cfg['email_address']),
                                                        'replyto'=>array('name'=>$this->cfg['email_from'], 'address'=>$this->cfg['email_address'])
                                                       );

            $mailheaders = $this->getMailHeaders($mailheaders_options)
                                    .$this->mail_content_type_format_charset_usernotification."\r\n"
                                    ;

            $mail_body = '';
            $mail_body .= $this->cfg['usernotification_message'];

            if($this->cfg['usernotification_insertformdata'])
            {
                $mail_body .= $this->mail_line_break_usernotification."--------------------------------------------------------";

                foreach($this->merge_post as $form_data)
                {
                    $mail_body .= $this->mail_line_break_usernotification.$this->mail_line_break_usernotification.$form_data['elementlabel_value'].': '.$form_data['element_value'];
                }
            }

            if(preg_match('#html#', $this->mail_content_type_format_charset_usernotification))
            {
                $mail_body = nl2br($mail_body);
            }

            @mail($value['email_address'], $this->cfg['usernotification_subject'], $mail_body, $mailheaders);
        }
    }

    function mergePost($value)
    {
        $this->merge_post[$this->merge_post_index]['element_id'] = $value['element_id'];
        $this->merge_post[$this->merge_post_index]['element_value'] = $this->quote_smart(trim($value['element_value']));
        $this->merge_post[$this->merge_post_index]['elementlabel_value'] = $this->quote_smart(trim($value['elementlabel_value']));
        $this->merge_post[$this->merge_post_index]['elementlabel_id'] = $this->quote_smart(trim($value['elementlabel_id']));

        if(isset($value['element_type']) && $value['element_type'])
        {   // if element_type == upload, we add the download link in the mail body message
            $this->merge_post[$this->merge_post_index]['element_type'] = trim($value['element_type']);
        }

        if(isset($value['filename']) && $value['filename'])
        {
            $this->merge_post[$this->merge_post_index]['filename'] = $this->quote_smart(trim($value['filename']));
        }

        if(isset($value['deletefile']) && $value['deletefile'])
        {
            $this->merge_post[$this->merge_post_index]['deletefile'] = trim($value['deletefile']);
        }

        $this->merge_post_index++;
    }


    function isEmail($email)
    {
        $atom   = '[-a-z0-9\\_]';   // authorized caracters before @
        $domain = '([a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9]+)?)'; // authorized caracters after @

        $regex = '/^' . $atom . '+' .   
        '(\.' . $atom . '+)*' .         

        '@' .                           
        '(' . $domain . '{1,63}\.)+' .  

        $domain . '{2,63}$/i';          

        // test de l'adresse e-mail
        return preg_match($regex, trim($email)) ? 1 : 0;

    }


    function quote_smart($value)
    {
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
            $value = stripslashes($value);
        }

        return $value;
    }



    function getMailHeaders($mailheaders_options)
    {
        $mailheaders_options['from']['name'] = isset($mailheaders_options['from']['name'])?$mailheaders_options['from']['name']:$mailheaders_options['from']['address'];

        $mailheaders_options['cc']['address'] = isset($mailheaders_options['cc']['address'])?$mailheaders_options['cc']['address']:'';

        $mailheaders_options['bcc']['address'] = isset($mailheaders_options['bcc']['address'])?$mailheaders_options['bcc']['address']:'';


        $from_name = $mailheaders_options['from']['name']?$mailheaders_options['from']['name']:$mailheaders_options['from']['address'];


        if($this->isEmail($from_name))
        {
            //  From: user@domain.com <user@domain.com> is invalid => user@domain.com
            $mail_header_from = 'From: '.$from_name."\r\n";
            $mail_header_replyto = 'Reply-To: '.$from_name."\r\n";
        } else
        {
            $mail_header_from = 'From: '.$from_name.'<'.$mailheaders_options['from']['address'].'>'."\r\n";
            $mail_header_replyto = 'Reply-To: '.$from_name.'<'.$mailheaders_options['from']['address'].'>'."\r\n";
        }


        $mail_header_cc = '';
        if($mailheaders_options['cc']['address'])
        {

            $explode_email = explode(',', $mailheaders_options['cc']['address']);

            $cc = '';

            foreach($explode_email as $email_value)
            {
                $cc .= $email_value.",";
            }

            $mail_header_cc .= 'Cc: '.substr($cc, 0, -1)."\r\n";
        }

        $mail_header_bcc = '';
        if($mailheaders_options['bcc']['address'])
        {
            $explode_email = explode(',', $mailheaders_options['bcc']['address']);

            $bcc = '';

            foreach($explode_email as $email_value)
            {
                $bcc .= $email_value.",";
            }

            $mail_header_bcc .= 'Bcc: '.substr($bcc, 0, -1)."\r\n";

        }

        $mailheaders =  $mail_header_from
                                .$mail_header_cc
                                .$mail_header_bcc
                                .$mail_header_replyto
                                .'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n"
                                .'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion()."\r\n"
                                ;
        /*
        Examples of headers that should work would be:
            From: user@domain.com will work
            From: "user" <user@domain.com>

        Examples of headers that will NOT work:
            From: "user@domain.com"
            From: user @ domain.com
            From: user@domain.com <user@domain.com>                             
        */

        //  echo $mailheaders;
        return($mailheaders);

    }


}

/**
 * NO SPACES AFTER THIS LINE TO PREVENT
 * Warning: Cannot modify header information
 */
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a honeypod is that most of the spambots can't execute javascript. So you do the folowwing:

1. Add a field with a spam question (as you did)
2. Fill in the correct value with javascript
3. Hide the field **with javascript**
4. Check the answer from the submitted form against the correct answer in the form processing PHP script

So you ensure that someone who has  javascript disabled (like a spambot) sees the input field and can insert the answer to your question manually.

All this points implemented could look like this:

```
<?php

$formErrorMsgs = array();

if(isset($_GET['send'])) {
    if(!isset($_POST['byebye_answer']) || $_POST['byebye_answer'] != 'stackoverflow')
        $formErrorMsgs[] = 'Please enter the correct answer for the antispam question';

    // all the other checks for the form input

    if(count($formErrorMsgs) <= 0) {
        // do the database insert or whatever here

        // redirect to another page or something like that afterwards
    }
}

?>
<form method="post" action="?send">
    <?php echo (count($formErrorMsgs) > 0)?'<ul><li>' , implode('</li><li>', $formErrorMsgs) , '</li></ul>':null; ?>

    <!-- all the regular input fields -->

    <dl class="byebye">
        <dt><label for="byebye-answer">Type in <b>stackoverflow</b></label></dt>
        <dd><input type="text" id="byebye-answer" name="byebye_answer"></dd>
    </dl>
</form>

<script>
    // if you're using jQuery do this

    (function() {
        $('#byebye-answer').val('stackoverflow');
        $('.byebye').hide();
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: so i do not even have to do anything with the php file. I found the way to implement this here http://pageaffairs.com/notebook/contact-form-honeypots however it is not clear on the third part of where to place the code. Check it out and you will see what I mean.

Comment: You have to check the answer for the spam question in your PHP script of course.

Comment: Thank you I am running out of fuel. I will test what you have put up. I thank you for all your hard work, what can I say I am new to php. It appears confusing to me at first, however so did HTML in the beginning. Again appreciate what you have done.